# Extruding along Normals equally

Tags: normals, extrude

I'm new in Blender and I'm facing a problem which I couldn't find any solution yet. Normally when the cube is equally in all the faces, extruding along normals works perfect. But when the faces are not equal, is there a chance to extrude them equally along normals? please check the picture to understand it better.
[image]

1,2 and 3 corners are by default when I extrude them along normals and press S for offset Even option,(see that one face is goes out more than the other) but I want to equally extrude them like the example nr.4 ( Which I moved the vertices manually) I'm working on a bulding that has a lot of these examples and I was thinking if there is an option to automatically fix that.
I would really appreciate your help

Comment: Your object is probably scaled in Object Mode. Try Ctrl-A Apply Scale.

Comment: You saved my life, thank you so much <3